VFP closing a form while excel doc is open
I currently have a foxpro form which opens a .xls excel doc, the issue is that I cannot close the foxpro form while the excel doc is still open.
This is what I have for opening the excel doc:
excelDoc = CREATEOBJECT("wscript.shell")
excelDoc.run("Excel"+ " " +  filePath, 3, .T.)

What happens if you RELEASE excelDoc?

I've tried that, none of the buttons on the form can be clicked and the cursor is stuck as a loading circle when hovering over the form. As soon as the excel is closed, the forms buttons return to being clickable

Why are you using wscript.shell in the first place? You are creating a dependency to having it released.
Simply use ShellExecute. ie:
#define SW_HIDE             0
#define SW_SHOWNORMAL       1
#define SW_SHOWMINIMIZED    2
#define SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED    3
#define SW_MAXIMIZE         3
#define SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE   4
#define SW_SHOW             5
#define SW_MINIMIZE         6
#define SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE  7
#define SW_SHOWNA           8
#define SW_RESTORE          9
#define SW_SHOWDEFAULT      10
#define SW_FORCEMINIMIZE    11
#define SW_MAX              11

declare long ShellExecute in "shell32.dll" ;
    long hwnd, string lpszOp, ;
    string lpszFile, string lpszParams, ;
    string lpszDir, long nShowCmd


ShellExecute(0,'Open','c:\MyFolder\blahblah.xls','','',SW_SHOWNORMAL)

